# Stop recognition in Swift3 without stop word

Tags: ios, swift3, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm attempting to simplify usage of the Speech framework in a textview. I can easily start the speech recognition process with code based on entering the textview, startup code or other actions. However, I also want to END the speech recognition without user touches. I have not been able to find anything in the Speech framework to indicate that there are methods available to do this. I have crafted a way to accomplish it by defining a word to be the trigger to stop transcription and then to remove the word from the transcription. It does work, but of course the user can never speak that word. Is there a better way to handle this concept?  iOS 10, Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.1

Here's the subset of code for the recognitionTask:

```
private var bufferedString = String()
private var stopWord = "myStopWord"

recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
let startText = self.sayTextView.text
bufferedString = ""

recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
    var finished = false

    if let result = result {

        self.bufferedString = startText! + result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.sayTextView.text = self.bufferedString
            finished = result.isFinal

    }//if let result

    //for testing
    self.stopWord = "Relationship"
    //for testing

    if self.bufferedString.lowercased().contains(self.stopWord.lowercased()) {
        print("buffered string contains \(self.stopWord)")

        if let stopWordRange = self.bufferedString.lowercased().range(of: self.stopWord.lowercased()) {
            self.bufferedString.replaceSubrange(stopWordRange, with: "")
            self.sayTextView.text = self.bufferedString
        }//if let

        self.stopRecording(self)

    }//if contains - look for stopWord

    if error != nil || finished {

        self.audioEngine.stop()
        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

        self.recognitionRequest = nil
        self.recognitionTask = nil
        self.startRecordingButton.isEnabled = true

    }//if error
})//recognitionTask resultHandler
```

Comment: You need to define when do you want to stop recognition, do you want to stop it right after start? What is the sense to start it then? Or do you want it to stop it after some time delay? Timeout should help then.

Comment: I want to stop when the user says a specified word. In the above code, when the user says "Relationship" it stops. Then relationship is removed from the text. Without any code from me, the user can say "comma" and get a comma. The user can say "question mark" and get a question mark. I can not find a reference to a stop word.

Comment: Did you try using a NSTimer ?

Comment: Timing is not really the issue - I don't want to wait for a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that isFinal flag doesn't became true when user stops talking as expected. I guess this is a wanted behaviour by Apple, because the event "User stops talk" is an undefined event.

I believe that the easiest way to achieve your goal is the follow:

- You have to estabilish an "interval of silence" that means if the user doesn't talk for a time greater than your interval he has stopped talking (i.e. 2 seconds).
- Create a Timer at the beginning of the audio session:

var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "didFinishTalk", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

- when you get new transcriptions in `recognitionTask`invalidate and restart your timer

  timer.invalidate()
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "didFinishTalk", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
- if the timer expires this means the user doesn't talk from 2 seconds. You can safely stop Audio Session and exit